# Why are snapPoints memorizades with useMemo react-native-bottom-sheet

Tags: react-native, react-usememo, react-usecallback

Why the documentation use `useCallback` and `useMemo` to memorize the props passed for the `BottomSheet`, what the performance win with this?

https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/usage

```js
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';

const App = () => {
  // ref
  const bottomSheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);

  // variables
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['25%', '50%'], []);

  // callbacks
  const handleSheetChanges = useCallback((index: number) => {
    console.log('handleSheetChanges', index);
  }, []);

  // renders
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BottomSheet
        ref={bottomSheetRef}
        index={1}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        onChange={handleSheetChanges}
      >
        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
          <Text>Awesome </Text>
        </View>
      </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 24,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is an unnecessary optimization.
At least in this example.

There is no performance boost from memoization since there are no heavy computations inside those functions.

However, it is possible the author used them as a possible placeholder when heavier computations to calculate snap points or change event handler needs to be optimized.

Here's a nice explanation of when these hooks are needed.

https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/usememo-and-usecallback/